# ComboBox's PointerPressed event in Windows 8 does not work

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

I encountered a strange behavior with ComboBox today. PointerPressed event in ComboBox never fires if you press the left mouse button. It only fires if you click the right mouse button. Can anybody please tell me why it is happening? I want to use left mouse button to fire the PointerPressed event.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" Width="200" Height="60" PointerPressed="ComboBox_PointerPressed_1">
        <ComboBox.Items>
            <TextBlock Text="test1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="test2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="test3"/>
        </ComboBox.Items>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>

private void ComboBox_PointerPressed_1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: no we cant tell you why its happening, and we never will until you show us the code, there may be a good reason why it wont do it

Comment: There is nothing in the code. It can be easily reproduced by just putting few items inside the ComboBox and attaching PointerPressed event. You will see that the event never fires.

Comment: no, i dont see that problem, for me the event fires. without an example of code where it deosnt work what do you expect us to do?

Comment: I have modified my question with the code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: This combobox just literally the only thing on the control (not in a datatemplate etc?)

Comment: Also, I am working on Windows 8 metro app.

Comment: This is just a "Hello world" sample. In my actual application, I am using a DataTemplate for ComboBox.

Comment: NeverMind, I am able to solve it as suggested here. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/04f70091-7f33-4646-9dce-fc5557e3f946